# parent.setChild is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

In many to many associations

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
var permission = req.body
models.Permission.create(permission)
  .then(function(data){
  if(permission.roles){
    var roles = permission.roles.map(models.Role.build.bind(models.Role));
    data.setRole(roles);
  }
  res.json(data)
 })
});
```

It gives error on data.setRole(roles) `data.setRole is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it one to many relationship between permission and roles then try

```
 data.setRoles(roles);
```